# multi thread read write with aligned int

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, lock-free

I have the following program.

```
class A {
  struct {
    int d1;
    int d2;
  } m_d;

  int onTimer() {
    return  m_d.d1 + m_d.d2;
  }

  void update(int d1, int d2) {
    m_d.d1 = d1;
    m_d.d2 = d2;
  }
};
```

`A::update` and `A::onTimer` are called by two different threads. Assuming that

1. x64 platform
2. every time `onTimer` is called, the result has to be up to date such that the sum is calculated using the most updated values of `m_d.d1` and `m_d.d2` instead of cached values
3. it is **fine** if `onTimer` is called during `update` that the sum is calculated with updated `m_d.d1` and old `m_d.d2`.
4. the class object is naturally aligned
5. no worry about reordering
6. speed is critical

then do I need to do any of the following

1. use `volatile` keyword so that the `m_d.d1` and `m_d.d2` are not stored in cache.
2. use any locks

Comment: `volatile` is no solution for any thread synchronization.

Comment: Using `volatile` won't help (as Dieter said). Using locks is a good idea if you want reliable behaviour (if you don't care about the accuracy of the result, as you indicate, then you can continue not locking).

Comment: @DieterLücking the reason I want to use `volatile` is to avoid using old cached values instead of the updated ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for the compiler to rearrange the order of the code and it is also possible for the CPU to reorder the reads and stores.  If you don't care that sometimes m_d.d1 and m_d.d2 will be values from different calls to update() then you need no locking.  Understand this means you might get an old m_d.d1 and a new m_d.d2, or vice versa.  The order of the code in the thread setting the values does not control the order another thread sees the values change.  You said "5) no worry about reordering", so i'm saying no locking required.

On the x86 int mov is "atomic" in that another thread reading the same int will see the previous value or the new value but not some random bunch of bits.    This means that m_d.d1 will always be a d1 that was passed into update(), and the same goes for m_d.d2.

volatile tells the compiler to not used a cached copy of a value (in a register).  You might find volatile necessary if you had a loop that kept trying to add those values while they were being modified by another thread.

```
void func {
    // smart optimizing compiler might move d1 into AX and d2 into BX here,
    // OUTSIDE the loop, because the compiler doesn't see anything in 
    // the loop changing d1 or d2.  
    // The compiler does this because it saves 2 moves per iteration.
    // This is referred to as "caching values in registers"
    // by laymen like me.
    while (1) {
       printf("%d", m_d.d1 + m_d.d2);  // might be using same initially
                                       // "cached" AX, BX every iteration
    }
}
```

That is not the case in your example, as you have a function call that adds them (unless the function were inlined).  A function won't have any values cached in registers when it is called, so it has to get a copy from memory.  I suppose if you want to be really super sure nothing ever got cached ever, you could do something like this:

```
int onTimer() {
    auto p = (volatile A*)this;
    return  p->m_d.d1 + p->m_d.d2;
}
```

Comment: could you explain the part with `volatile` needed if the function were inlined?  If I don't use `volatile`, does `onTimer` use old values of d1 and d2 stored in L1 or L2 cache?

Comment: No L1 and L2 has nothing to do with volatile.  That's not the cache people refer to when they say compiler caches values. See edit.

Comment: I worry about inlining because then there is no function call anymore.  The line m_d.d1 + m_d.d2 is now just code in the middle of another function which might very well have a loop like I described.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mention that it is OK if `onTimer` observes a partially updated `m_d`, you don't need a mutex guarding the entire object.  However, C++ makes no guarantee about the atomicity of `int`.  For maximum portability and correctness, you should use an [atomic `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).  Atomic operations allow you specify a [memory order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) that declares what kind of guarantees you require.  Because you say that it is critical that `onTimer` not use cached values, I would recommend you use "Release-Acquire ordering."  This is less strict than the default ordering used by `std::atomic`, but it's all you need here:

> If an atomic store in thread A is tagged `memory_order_release` and an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged `memory_order_acquire`, all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B, that is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory.

Using the above guide, your code might look something like the following.  Note that you can't use the `operator T()` conversion of the `atomic_int` because it is equivalent to `load()`, which defaults to the `std::memory_order_seq_cst` ordering, which is too strict for your needs.

```
class A {
  struct {
    std::atomic_int d1;
    std::atomic_int d2;
  } m_d;

  int onTimer() {
    return m_d.d1.load(std::memory_order_acquire) +
           m_d.d2.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  }

  void update(int d1, int d2) {
    m_d.d1.store(d1, std::memory_order_release);
    m_d.d2.store(d2, std::memory_order_release);
  }
};
```

Note that this ordering should be free in your case (x86_64), but doing due diligence here will aid portability and eliminate undesired compiler optimizations:

> On strongly-ordered systems (x86, SPARC TSO, IBM mainframe), release-acquire ordering is automatic for the majority of operations. No additional CPU instructions are issued for this synchronization mode, only certain compiler optimizations are affected (e.g. the compiler is prohibited from moving non-atomic stores past the atomic store-release or perform non-atomic loads earlier than the atomic load-acquire). On weakly-ordered systems (ARM, Itanium, PowerPC), special CPU load or memory fence instructions have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The only practical answer here is a `std::mutex`.

There's also the atomic operations library. Given condition 3, it might be possible that you could get away with a pair of atomic ints. Still, I would recommend an old-fashioned mutex-protected object. Fewer surprises.

Comment: what if speed is critical here, I need the program to run as fast as possible.

Comment: At least on Linux, mutexes are lightweight, and fast. I find in my experience that if I focus on doing what I think is right, the rest will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I don't think you need any lock. If you don't use inline function, maybe the volatile is not needed neither.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell . Your have only 1 thread to modify the datas. And you don't need the modify of both m_d.d1 and m_d.d2 to be a atomic operation . So there is no need to use any lock .

If you have 2 or more threads to update a data and the new value has relationship with previous value , then you can use `std::atomic<>` to protect it.

If you need the update of 2 or more data become a atomic operation , then use `std::mutex` to protect them.